# How to get the contentedible html element to expand downward inside its container

Tags: html, css

If a user writes in content, I want the paragraph to only grow in the downward direction while the  `div` which has the id of `description` grows along with it in the same direction.  The final parent `div` with the id of `documentation` stays in the same position so that it does not grow upwards. Lets assume that this block of code is in the middle of the html doc. So, how exactly do I anchor it in place so that is grows in the correct direction? Thanks.

**Index.html**

```
<div id="documentation">
            <div id="description" >
                <p contenteditable="true"></p>
                </div>      
            </div>
```

**Style.css**

```
#documentation{
    border:2px solid yellow;
}

#description{
    width:500px;
    border:2px solid black;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:50px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    }

#description p{
word-break:break-all;
border:2px solid red;
width:400px;    
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me, I'm confused about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try styling the #documentation instead of description

```css
#documentation{
    border:2px solid yellow;
    height: 500px; /*or some fixed height*/
    overflow: auto;
}
```